# Using a const in a URL onclick event

Tags: javascript

Im trying to build a cheaty kinda multilingual site in wordpress (interim fix) and need to set the logo link to go the the correct landing page when clicked, either /en/ or /se/.

Im trying to do this by grabing the url and then splitting the path name.

`

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
const firstpath = location.pathname.split('/')[1];
</script>

<a href="/" onclick="location.href=this.href+firstpath;return false;">
    <img  />
</a>
```

`

fairly sure im missing something simple, especially as it did work awhile ago until I changed something that i dont remember :/

When clicked the link shoulf return:
root/first-folder-of-current-url

MORE DETAILS:
(sorry fairly new here)

So I have a two folder hierarcy /en/ and /se/.

When in the /en/ folder if i click the logo I should be taken back to the root/en/ folder.

When in the /se/ folder if i click the logo I should be taken back to the root/se/ folder.

I cant have unique code for each folder so stuck trying to make this work with a javascript link.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: remove `href="/"`, it's conflicting with your onclick=..

Comment: Removing the href="/" would make it unclickable (double checked) and having an empty href does nothing.
In general there shouldnt be a conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression instead. (Regular expressions are how we look for patterns in strings of text in JavaScript. You can read about them here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Also, instead of using the `onclick` event, `<a>` tags already include a function for creating a hyperlink using JavaScript, by writing `javascript:` in the href attribute. That might be more compatible with WordPress.

In your case, it would go like this:

```
<a href="javascript:location.href=location.href.match( new RegExp( '^.*://.*/(en|se)/' ) )[ 0 ];">
    <img  />
</a>
```

This regular expression, `^.*://.*/(en|se)/`, works like this:
`^`: Means [At the beginning of the string]
`.*`: Means [One or more of any character]
`://` Means what it says, `"://"`. This is in every URL, like https://www.google.com
`.*` Means [One or more of any character]
`/(en|se)/` Means [Slash "/", followed by "en" or "se", followed by slash "/"]

The `.match()` function finds matches for the pattern we described, and returns them in an array. We only want the first entry of that array, so we specify `.match( ... )[ 0 ]`

Comment: So I do understand how and why this should work but its still not working. 
Im going to have to dig deeper I think and see if there is something in wordpress blocking it.

Weirdly it looks ok in inspector and there are no console issues with either solution :/

Comment: Instead of using onclick, you should probably put the JavaScript in the HREF. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative by simply replacing the content of the href:

```
<a href="#" id="homelink">
<img src="URL" />
</a>
<script>
document.getElementById("homelink").href ='/'+location.pathname.split('/')[1];
</script>
```

Comment: Quick comment, tested this solution as well in more detail but iphone safari ignores the rewrite. Thought id share :)